# Generating multiple SAS programs using `filename` statements

Tags: sas, code-generation

I have one large dataset that specifies metadata for variables across datasets in different libnames (pulled from `sashelp.vcolumn`.

Running through this I have code along the lines of the following which outputs one large program - this is working fine. However I've since found out I will need to divert the filename to generate a program in the appropriate directory for each new libname it comes across:

```
data _null_ ;
  set metadata end=eof ;
  by libname memname ;
  file sascode ;

  if first.libname then put "proc datasets lib=" libname " nolist ;";
  if first.memname then put "  modify "memname ";";
  if last.libname then  put "  run;
  if eof then           put "quit ;";
run ;
```

Is it possible to redirect the `file` statement to the correct directory for each `first.libname`?

Comment: When you say `divert the filename` you mean make a new file each time the libname changes?

Comment: Hi Joe - thanks, yes I'm trying to end up with a unique program written to each libname directory

Comment: Have you looked at the filevar option in the file statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Reeza's answer a bit, here is how you'd do it using the metadata in `dictionary.libnames`.  I use `dictionary.tables` here, but if you need to use `.columns` to get (whatever you're doing with the columns) that should work just as well.

```
libname temp 'c:\temp';
data class temp.class;
set sashelp.class;
run;

proc sql;
  create table metadata as
    select T.libname, T.memname, L.path
    from dictionary.tables T, dictionary.libnames L
    where T.libname=L.libname
    and T.memname='CLASS'
    and level=0 /* this eliminates SASHELP lib which is a bit crazy */
    ;
quit;


data _null_ ;
  set metadata end=eof;
  by libname path memname ;
  fn = cats(path,'\sasfile.sas');
  file sascode filevar=fn;

  if first.libname then put "proc datasets lib=" libname " nolist ;";
  if first.memname then put "  modify " memname ";";
  if last.libname then  put "  run; quit;";
run ;
```

Comment: Thanks Joe - pulling in the paths from dictionary tables too - perfect :-) @Reeza thank you too - I upvoted too. Joe, just out of interest - why do you say "...SASHELP lib which is a bit crazy"?

Comment: SASHELP is a combined lib, which has 11 directories (or so) making it up.  So you'd have a lot of files generated for that.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `FILEVAR` option in the file statement.

From SAS KB24599 : http://support.sas.com/kb/24/599.html

```
/* Create sample data */

data test;
  input color $ num;
datalines;
blue 1
blue 2
blue 3
green 4
green 5
red 6
red 7
red 8
;

data _null_;
  length fname $30.;
  set test;     
  by color;                                               
  if first.color then count+1;
  fname="C:\TEMP\file" || trim(left(put(count,8.)))||".txt";
  file dummy filevar=fname;
  put color num count;
run;
```